# An Issue with LI Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

The `UL.Categories LI A:Active` part won't work correctly. It applies the style while I hold a click on the link, once I release the click it returns to its default style. I've included both my old JS and new JS. I didn't know how to include my Old JS to the HTML part multiple times (it works only on one, but as soon as I duplicated the HTML content, it looses its style), so I made the New JS, though Old JS worked marvellously with the HTML part. The New JS won't keep the `UL.Categories LI A:Active` style... Any help?

Old JS:

```
<SCRIPT>
$(function()
{
  $('UL.Categories LI:First').addClass('TheActiveTab');
  $('.CategoriesContents ARTICLE').hide();
  $('.CategoriesContents ARTICLE:First').show();
  $('UL.Categories LI').on('click',function()
{
    $('UL.Categories LI').removeClass('TheActiveTab');
    $(this).addClass('TheActiveTab')
    $('.CategoriesContents ARTICLE').hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(activeTab).show();
    return false;
  });
})
</SCRIPT>
```

New JS:

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.Categories > LI > #ATB').click(function()
{
    $('.CategoriesContents > #About').fadeIn(800); //fadeToggle()/show();
    $('.CategoriesContents > #Editions').hide(); return false;
});
$('.Categories > LI > #EDIT').click(function()
{
    $('.CategoriesContents > #Editions').fadeIn(800);
    $('.CategoriesContents > #About').hide(); return false;
});

$('.Categories2 > LI > #ATB').click(function()
{
    $('.CategoriesContents2 > #About').fadeIn(800); //fadeToggle()/show();
    $('.CategoriesContents2 > #Editions').hide(); return false;
});
$('.Categories2 > LI > #EDIT').click(function()
{
    $('.CategoriesContents2 > #Editions').fadeIn(800);
    $('.CategoriesContents2 > #About').hide(); return false;
});
});
</SCRIPT>
```

CSS:

```
UL.Categories,
UL.Categories2
{
    BORDER: 1px Solid #FFF;
    WIDTH: 100%;
    DISPLAY: Table;
    MARGIN: 0 0 0 0;
    LIST-STYLE-TYPE: None;
    PADDING: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: 1px Solid #404040;
}
UL.Categories LI,
UL.Categories2 LI
{
    BORDER: 1px Solid #FFF;
    FLOAT: Left;
    HEIGHT: 50px;
    WIDTH: Auto;
    MARGIN: 0 0 0 0;
    DISPLAY: Table-Cell;
    WHITE-SPACE: NoWrap;
    TEXT-ALIGN: Center !important;
    PADDING: 12px 20px 7px 20px !important;
}
UL.Categories LI A:Link,
UL.Categories LI A:Visited
{
    BORDER: 1px Solid #FFF;
    FONT-SIZE: 20px;
    FONT-STYLE: Normal;
    FONT-WEIGHT: Normal;
    TEXT-DECORATION: None;
    COLOR: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    TEXT-TRANSFORM: UpperCase;
    FONT-FAMILY: "Modricha" !important;
    -WEBKIT-FONT-SMOOTHING: Antialiased;
    -KHTML-FONT-SMOOTHING: Antialiased;
    -MOZ-FONT-SMOOTHING: Antialiased;
    -MS-FONT-SMOOTHING: Antialiased;
    -O-FONT-SMOOTHING: Antialiased;
    FONT-SMOOTHING: Antialiased;
}
UL.Categories LI A:Hover,
UL.Categories2 LI A:Hover
{
    BORDER: 1px Solid #FFF;
    PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px;
    TEXT-DECORATION: None;
}
UL.Categories LI A:Active,
UL.Categories2 LI A:Active
{
    BORDER: 1px Solid #FFF;
    TOP: 0;
    HEIGHT: 100%;
    POSITION: Relative;
    COLOR: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) !important;
    ➛ BORDER-BOTTOM: 5px Solid #95B5AF !important;
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: Transparent;
    ➛ TRANSITION: All 0.2s Ease 0s;
    -O-TRANSITION: All 0.2s Ease 0s;
    -MS-TRANSITION: All 0.2s Ease 0s;
    -MOZ-TRANSITION: All 0.2s Ease 0s;
    -KHTML-TRANSITION: All 0.2s Ease 0s;
    -WEBKIT-TRANSITION: All 0.2s Ease 0s;
    BOX-SIZING: Border-Box;
    -O-BOX-SIZING: Border-Box;
    -MS-BOX-SIZING: Border-Box;
    -MOZ-BOX-SIZING: Border-Box;
    -KHTML-BOX-SIZING: Border-Box;
    -WEBKIT-BOX-SIZING: Border-Box;
}
ARTICLE
{
    BORDER: 0;
    PADDING: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<UL class="Categories">
<LI>
<A href="#About" id="ATB">About This Book</A>
</LI>
<LI class="Kate">
<A href="#Editions" id="EDIT">Editions</A>
</LI>
</UL>
<DIV class="TheCleaner"></DIV>
<SECTION class="CategoriesContents">
<ARTICLE id="About" class="Description"></ARTICLE>
<ARTICLE id="Editions" class="Description" style="DISPLAY: None"></ARTICLE>
</SECTION>
```

Comment: that is the idea of :active - once you go off it it's not active anymore?

Comment: use :focus to maintain the style

Comment: @RachelGallen :active style is lost while I am still on it.

Comment: Still the same after :focus. The `BORDER-BOTTOM: 5px Solid #95B5AF !important;` does not stay active...

Comment: browser compatibility issue? What are you using?

Comment: Firefox, latest version...

Comment: if you want your style to apply all the time your mouse is on the object, you better stick with the :hover event. active will only work when the object is activated like being clicked. when you release the click, it will go back to the original state.

Comment: That's the point, Ryan. Link is clicked, but the style for that link in its :active state is not active...